# What's the role of commutation relations in stochastic mechanics?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

In a stochastic context, we can understand a term like
 $$ \int_0^T \frac{d q(t)}{dt}  dq $$ 
either as the (Ito) limit
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i}^N  dq(t_i) \frac{d q(t_i)}{dt}     $$
or the (Anti-Ito) limit
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i}^N \frac{d q(t_i)}{dt}  dq(t_i+\epsilon_i)  , $$
where we divided the interval $[0,T]$ in equal slices with width $\epsilon$. Moreover, I've written the terms in a time-ordered manner and we have
$$\frac{d q(t_i)}{dt}  \equiv \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \frac{q(t_i+\epsilon_i) - q(t_i)}{\epsilon} \, . $$

For Brownian motion we also have 
$$ \langle \Delta q(t_i) \rangle \equiv \langle  q(t_i+ \epsilon) -  q(t_i) \rangle  = \sqrt{\epsilon} \, .  $$
This implies
\begin{align}
1 &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \langle  \frac{(\Delta q(t_i) )^2}{\epsilon} \rangle  \\
 &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 }  \langle \frac{( q(t_i+ \epsilon) -  q(t_i)  )^2}{\epsilon} \rangle  \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0 }  \langle  \frac{ \Big(  q(t_i+ \epsilon) -  q(t_i) \Big)q(t_i+ \epsilon) -  q(t_i) \Big(  q(t_i+ \epsilon) -  q(t_i) \Big) }{\epsilon}   \rangle \\
&=  \langle  \frac{d q(t_i)}{dt}q(t_i)  - q(t_i) \frac{d q(t_i)}{dt}   \rangle 
\end{align}
We can read off here
$$ \langle [\frac{d q(t_i)}{dt},q(t_i)] \rangle \equiv \langle \frac{d q(t_i)}{dt}q(t_i)  - q(t_i) \frac{d q(t_i)}{dt} \rangle  = 1 $$
*This is quite similar to the canonical commutation relations in quantum mechanics.* Thus I was wondering if commutation relations like this play a role in other (stochastic) contexts too? If yes, is there something analogous to the uncertainty relation for more general stochastic processes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, there is a close  relationship between Ito's formula for stochastic integrals and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. This connection is outlined in  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414910000256 (Ito’s stochastic calculus and Heisenberg commutation relations, by P. Biane). For a generalization of such kind of uncertainty relation, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960118303633 (Generalization of uncertainty relation for quantum and stochastic systems, by T. Koide and T. Kodama).